# How to sum arrays within an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Basically i have `array = [[1 2 3],[4 5 6]]`
I want to sum the values within 1 array to get `sum_array = [6,15]`.
I have tried `sum(array)` on my actual dataset and got random numbers.(not the anticipated output).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) can only be performed on an element that is configured with `__add__` to handle it. For a `list` it needs to be, in a loose sense `single dimensioned`. Hence you need to get the `flattened list` inside.

Using `List comprehension`.

```
>>> [sum(l) for l in array]
=> [6, 15]
```

Using `map`

```
>>> list( map(sum, array) )
=> [6, 15]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: Lists and iterables don't really have dimensions, and even so, `sum` *could* work with say, `x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, so try `sum(x, [])`, it just might not do what you expect. Even for `numpy.ndarray` objects, which do have dimensions, `sum` does work since they implement `__add__` in a way that works, so consider `arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)` and `sum(arr)`

Comment: My point is simply that `sum` works as long as for each element in the iterable, `e1 + e2` works.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from existing answers, you can also use `map` and `sum` together for a better and cleaner approach:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
sumArray = map(sum, array)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> sumArray
[6, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum(array)` as you suggested, just make sure you're creating a list with the values returned by sum:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
sums = [sum(x) for x in array]
>> [6, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `list comprehension` along with `sum` eases the above task.

```
a = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] ]
sum_list = [ sum[elem] for elem in a ]
print(sum_list)
#Output [6,15]
```

The below approach is lengthy, but I feel it is easier to understand for the beginner

```
array = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
sum_list = []

for elements in array:
    elements_sum = 0
    for elem in elements:
        elements_sum = elements_sum + elem
    sum_list.append(elements_sum)
print(sum_list)
#Output [6,15]
```

Answer (score -1):

and if you want the full sum of the array of array

do that

```
print(sum(list(map(sum, array)))
```

this will give you 21